# How to get callback on netty client after server establish sslConnection

Tags: java, netty

My server expects clients to connect on two different sockets and order of connection is important. Client must connect on first channel `ch1` and after SSL handshake server takes time to create user session. In Handler it looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {           
        log.debug("channelRegistered);
        ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class).handshakeFuture().addListener(
                future -> initSession(ctx));
    }
```

InitSession method create internal objects to track client. Only after initSession is complete server expect connection on second channel `ch2` from this client.

I'm stuck with writing client code to perform this connection order.
Naive way is easy:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            SslContext sslContext = provideSslContext();
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new Channelinitializer(sslContext));

            Channel ch1 = b.connect("localhost", 8008).sync().channel();

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            Bootstrap b1 = new Bootstrap();
            b1.group(workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new Channelinitializer(sslContext));

            Channel ch2 = b1.connect("localhost", 8009).sync().channel();
        }finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
```

After `ch1` connect we just wait for some time to be sure that server perform all actions required.
How robust solution should look like? Is there any callback I can use to trigger `ch2` connection? I'm using netty 4.0.36.Final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just retrieve the `SslHandler` from the pipeline and wait on the `handshakeFuture` or add a listener to it. Then when it is complete do the second connect.

Something like:

```
 SslContext sslContext = provideSslContext();
 Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
 b.group(workerGroup)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .handler(new Channelinitializer(sslContext));

 Channel ch1 = b.connect("localhost", 8008).sync().channel();
 ch1.pipeline.get(SslHandler.class).handshakeFuture().sync()

 Bootstrap b1 = new Bootstrap();
 b1.group(workerGroup)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .handler(new Channelinitializer(sslContext));

 Channel ch2 = b1.connect("localhost", 8009).sync().channel();
```